# laravel: Password resetter [] is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, passwords

When I go to Laravel's password reset link (example.com/password/reset), write my email and click "Send Password Reset Link" button, it goes to example.com/password/email link and gives an error:

> [2018-07-21 17:59:35] local.ERROR: Password resetter [] is not
>   defined. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0):
>   Password resetter [] is not defined. at
>   /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBrokerManager.php:67)

I use Laravel 5.6
I should note that when I moved my Laravel project to new VPS, this error happened.
I use laravel on my VPS.
Whats the problem?

Comment: which version of laravel do you use?

Comment: I use laravel 5.6

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that this code exists in your `config/auth.php`.

```
'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: This code is already exist in config/auth.php and also the table 'password_resets' exist in mysql database. I should note that when I moved my laravel project to new VPS, this error happened.

Comment: In my case, for some reason the auth.php had `password` instead of `passwords`.

Comment: How to change the password table that Laravel changed? The above code changes the password in the `user` table, but what if I have another table? What steps should be taken to set it up?

Answer (score 1):

your routes should have name please check it:

```
Route::get('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.email');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');

// Password reset routes...
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@postReset')->name('password.reset');
```

Comment: Yes all of these are available when i use "php artisan route:list" command to see them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the key=>value pair:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

in your `config/auth.php`